# Django login with plain password

Tags: python, django

I had a db with usernames and password(plain text) and now I have to create an app of login so I needed a best way that how can I create a login can I use django registration or any other django default apps of login so which makes my work easy What I had been tried is:

I had created a duplicate table and tried to encrypt it with this code but it didn't work

```
  import crypt
   # To encrypt the password. This creates a password hash with a random salt.
   password_hash = crypt.crypt(password)
   # To check the password.
   valid_password = crypt.crypt(cleartext, password_hash) == password_hash
```

Comment: need more details, what you mean `did not work`

Comment: How about https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create registration app, you can use Google search for tutorial. Second link in Google https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html

Based on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/
If you need to fill your users table.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
users_dict = {
    'johndoe': {'email':'johndoe@doe.com', 'password': '12345678'}
}
for username, data in users_dict.items():
    user = User.objects.create_user(username, data['email'], data['password'])
```